# ReactJS main Component to access dynamic data from outside its scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use ReactJS to fix a page that was implemented wholly in jQuery, by writing a React Component to handle the error-prone section of the page. The page is an Edit Tasks page, that contains multiple sections, one of which is called the Payrates section

The state of the page can be described thus:

It contains a collection of `TaskObject`s, each of which have `Payrates` and `Permissions`.

I am trying to pass in the `Payrates`, which of course change with click on another task (the UI element of another `TaskObject`.

To get rolling, I made a stub `pageState`, declared globally, which has the following implementation:

```
function createPageState() { 
  let _currentTaskObject;

  return {
    getCurrentTaskObject : () => _currentTaskObject,
    setCurrentTaskObject : (taskObject) => _currentTaskObject = taskObject,
    getTaskPayRates : () => {
      if (_currentTaskObject) { 
        return _currentTaskObject.Payrates
      }
      return [];
    }
  }
}

let pageState = createPageState()
```

Upon click of a Task, `pageState.setCurrentTaskObject` gets invoked.

The React main Component has the following implementation:

```
class PayRatesContainerComponent extends React.Component { 

    constructor(props) { 
        super(props)
        const payRates = (typeof props.payRates === 'function') ? props.payRates() : props.payRates

        this.state = {
            payRates : payRates,
            errors : {
                rate : '',
                date : ''
            },
            currentPayRate : new PayRate(-1, -1, -1, null),
            selectedPayRateIndex : -1,
            payRateIndicesToDelete : [],
            dateString : ''

        }

        // binding done here; // TODO: look into an auto-binding third-party library to automate all this
        this.updateCurrentPayRate = this.updateCurrentPayRate.bind(this)
        this.updateCurrentPayRateDate = this.updateCurrentPayRateDate.bind(this)
        this.updateCurrentPayRateAmount = this.updateCurrentPayRateAmount.bind(this)
        this.updateSelectedPayRateIndex = this.updateSelectedPayRateIndex.bind(this)
        this.updatePayRateAt = this.updatePayRateAt.bind(this)
        this.checkForDuplicates = this.checkForDuplicates.bind(this)
    }

    // setup logic
    componentDidMount() { 

    }

    // teardown logic
    componentWillUnmount() { 

    }

    // business logic

    /**
     * @param { PayRate } newPayRate
     **/
    updateCurrentPayRate(newPayRate) { 
        this.setState({
            ...this.state, 
            currentPayRate : newPayRate
        })
    }

    updateCurrentPayRateDate(dateString) {
        // 
        this.setState({
            ...state,
            dateString : dateString
        })
        const newPayRate = Object.assign(new PayRate(), this.state.currentPayRate, { EffectiveDate : new Date(dateString) } )
        this.updateCurrentPayRate(newPayRate)
    }

    updateCurrentPayRateAmount(amount) { 
        const newPayRate = Object.assign(new PayRate(), this.state.currentPayRate, { Rate : Number(amount) } )
        this.updateCurrentPayRate(newPayRate)
    }

    updateSelectedPayRateIndex(newIndex = -1) { 
        const newPayRate = (newIndex === -1) ? 
            currentPayRate : 
            this.state.payrates[newIndex]

        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            selectedPayRateIndex : newIndex,
            currentPayRate : newPayRate
        })
    }

    updatePayRateAt(index = -1, newPayRate) { 
        const payRatesCount = this.state.payrates.length;

        if ((index >= payRatesCount) || (index < 0)) { 
            throw RangeError('index must correspond to the list of payrates')
        }


        if (index === -1) { 
            this.appendValue(newPayRate)
            return;
        } 
        let listOfPayRates = [
            ...this.state.payrates.slice(0, index),
            newPayRate,
            ...this.state.payrates.slice(index + 1)
        ]

        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            payrates: listOfPayRates,
            ...this.blankState
        })

    }

    /**
     * Checks for duplicates
     * @param { PayRate } newPayRate 
     * @returns whether or not there's pay rates dated the same as this
     */
    checkForDuplicates(newPayRate) {  

        // if there's no effective date to compare, we're done
        if (!newPayRate.EffectiveDate) { 
            return false;
        }

        // extract the date from newPayRate
        const date = newPayRate.GetReadableDate()

        // for all the pay rates on the list
        for (let idx in this.state.payrates) {
            const payrate = this.state.payrates[idx]
            // if we found one whose date matches, we're done here
            if ((payrate.GetReadableDate() === date) && 
                (this.state.selectedPayRateIndex != idx)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // what this Component shall render

    render() { 
        /**
         * the actual validator
         * @param {{payRate : PayRate, dateString : string}} value 
         */
        const validator = (value) => { 
            // check the payRate part
            let errors = validate(value.payRate)
            // now, check the dateString
            if (!value.dateString) { 
                errors.date = "Enter a date"
            }

            return errors
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row" style={{marginBottom: "5px"}}>
                    <div className="col-sm-6 text-left no-padding">
                        Default Pay Rates
                        <i className="fa fa-question text-primary"
                            data-toggle="tooltip"
                            title="When adding this task to an employee, if there are default pay rates they will automatically be added to the employee for that task. They can be modified after the task is added."
                            aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <PayRatesAddRemoveComponent 
                        payRateIndicesToDelete={this.state.payRateIndicesToDelete}/>
                </div>
                <PayRatesListComponent 
                    payRates={this.state.payRates}
                    selectedPayRateIndex={this.state.selectedPayRateIndex}
                    onChange={(e) => {

                    }}/>
                <NewPayRateRow 
                    value={this.state.currentPayRate} 
                    validator={validator}
                    onPayRateAmountChange={(value) => {}}
                    onPayRateDateChange={(value) => {}} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


// validation logic

/**
 * Validates a PayRate
 * @param { PayRate } value
 * @returns { Object } any errors
 **/
function validate(value = {}) { 
    // extract rate,date from value
    const rate = value.Rate,
          date = value.EffectiveDate

    let errors = {}

    // rate better resolve to something
    if (!rate) { 
        errors.rate = "Enter a valid pay rate amount"
    }

    // date better be valid
    if ((!date) || (!date.toLocaleDateString)) { 
        errors.date = "Enter a date"
    }
    else if (date.toLocaleDateString("en-US") === "Invalid Date") { 
        errors.date = "Enter a valid pay rate date"
    }

    return errors
}
```

Clicking a task updates the `_currentTaskObject` and its `Payrates` successfully, yet React doesn't know that. 
I get empty array when I go to inspect the React developer console.
[image]

What can I do to make React Component aware of changes to the state of the data it requires, short of rewriting the entire page in React?

Comment: I didn't get to run the code but it seems like `updateCurrentPayRateDate` sets the state like `{...state, dateString : dateString}`. and maybe it should be `{...this.state, dateString: dateString}`?

Comment: Thanks, but that has nothing to do with the problem at hand